# Accessing Windows Environment Variables in Jupyter

Tags: python, environment

I want to learn how to access client ids and secrets for APIs by setting them as Windows environment variables. I set a variable by going to my System Properties --> Advanced --> Environment Variables in Windows.

In my jupyter notebook, I tried to access it with both:

```
os.environ.get("client_id")

os.environ["client_id"]
```

and the variable does not load.